# Extract portion of date string and convert to datetime in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar

I'm running SQL Server Standard 2008 R2 on a 64 bit version of Windows Server 2008 R2 standard (sp1)

I've imported a log file as a flat file source. One of the columns from the import called `col2` in the table called `big` holds values like this: `16/Mar/2007:11:30:17` as `varchar(50)`.

I want to convert that column (`col2`) to a `datetime` datatype.

One method I was trying was to extract each part of the date string and then recombine and convert them.

The problem I ran into is that each column has different widths since the log file couldn't be neatly delimited, making using something like `CHARINDEX` return a single digit or sometimes NULL.

I've been attempting to set up using regex using CLR integration but can't get it to work (I can't create a C# project in Visual Studio, there's no option for it) and Master Data Services won't install because SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard doesn't support it.

What is my best method to do this? Using `CASE`, `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DECLARE @d varchar(50) = '16/Mar/2007:11:30:17'

SELECT CAST(STUFF(@d,CHARINDEX(':',@d),1,' ')  AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 2):

Though I liked the idea of EricZ, however, here is my solution

```
DECLARE @d varchar(50) = '16/Mar/2007:11:30:17'
SELECT CAST( LEFT(@d,PATINDEX('%:%',@d) - 1) + ' ' +  SUBSTRING(@d,PATINDEX('%:%',@d) + 1,LEN(@d)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(datetime, 
       SUBSTRING('16/Mar/2007:11:30:17', 0, CHARINDEX(':', '16/Mar/2007:11:30:17')) + ' ' +
       SUBSTRING('16/Mar/2007:11:30:17', CHARINDEX(':', '16/Mar/2007:11:30:17') + 1, 8) , 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this>

```
select convert(datetime,STUFF(big,CHARINDEX(':',big),1,' '),101) from yourtable
```

Example:Check here as datatime string format.If its the same it will work

```
DECLARE @d varchar(50) = '16/Mar/2007:11:30:17'
select convert(datetime,STUFF(@d,CHARINDEX(':',@d),1,' '),101)
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this one, tailoring it as: `select convert(datetime,STUFF(col2,CHARINDEX(':',col2),1,' '),101) 
from big`, and got: "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."